# When migrating to Swift 4, do I need to update 3.0 to 3.2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am planning to update my Swift version to Swift 4 and Xcode 9 but I realized the migration tool that Apple provides specifies Swift 3.2. I am currently running Swift 3.0 in Xcode 8.

**Do I need to update to Swift 3.2 (via Xcode 8.3.3) first before updating to Swift 4 (via Xcode 9)?**

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing that. If I can avoid potential errors I will do so. Also, I searched the web and no one can give me a definitive answer which is why I asked here.

Comment: Programmers try stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about translating your project in XCode from an earlier version of swift to the most recent, then ***no you do not need to update it to something in between, Xcode will do it for you***. Even if I am wrong and you did, Xcode will automatically do it for you. Keep in mind it will do the best it can but some things have changed dramatically. It is best to be familiar with the language and try to work on migrating your code piece by piece. I myself experienced this with an old project, where I had to take several classes a day and translate them until they no longer gave me errors. Took me about 4 days, where the amount of time it took was about 2-4 files an hour.

There is a big difference between needing to upgrade swift and needing to upgrade Xcode. Just take this with blind faith. Upgrade Xcode first always and make sure you do it completely. Then migrate swift. You are misunderstanding. The way swift is made, it does not matter if your code is 2.4, 3.1, 3.8. Upgrading to the newest version will be the same process. The only difference when upgrading from various lower version to the newest is that you have to convert from what ever version you are currently at to the newest version. Also if you are worried about making mistakes when you update then I strongly recommend that you save your project with source control. If you are unfamiliar with source control, then just alway have a backup copy of your original project before you started messing with it (I always found a way to mess stuff up doing it that way though, so just be really careful. I found using a separate flash drive prevented me from making silly mistakes).

Also, after reading the comments. I wanted to note that YOU SHOULD UPDATE YOUR OS FIRST lol. I guess I just kind of assumed that you had already done that XD

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel like I can make the changes myself but I was a bit confused by the migration tool specifying Swift 3.2. It seems like they're saying I need to Xcode 8.3.3 which will allow me to run Swift 3.2 then I can use the migration tool. Am I misunderstanding? I am concerned that if I don't have 3.2, It won't attempt to convert my code for me and will instead force me to do all manually.

Comment: I updated my OS and then updated Swift and it worked fine. And I do have source control so I can track the changes. Also, I understand the difference between updating Swift and Xcode. I did so for 2.2 to Swift 3 but at the time I had a supported version for migration. This time around I didn't so I wanted to make sure that Xcode would assist with the migration even though I had 3.0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, Swift is ship with XCode
For your reference:
https://swift.org/download/#releases

Comment: I am aware that Swift is shipped with Xcode. Regardless of that, I am still not sure if I need to update to Swift 3.2 (via Xcode 8.3.x) or if I can go directly to Swift 4 (via Xcode 9).

Comment: No you don't need to. In case you choose to download Xcode 9. just make sure your macOS is 10.12.6 or later

Comment: I'm running MacOS 10.12.3. I'm glad you pointed that out. I just realized the minimum requirements are 10.12.6. I guess I'll have to update my OS first.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. You do not have to update to Swift 3.2 before updating to Swift 4 as long as you have Swift 3.0 or higher. I updated to the latest MacOS and updated Xcode 9. There were no errors but I got a few warnings about the new string types and characters being deprecated.